# What is Custom Attribute in .NET

Tags: .net, attributes, custom-attributes

The question is not that simple :).

Basically, what I need to know is what will be included into an array returned from any method from a family of `Attribute.GetCustomAttributes()` methods.

Definitely, all attributes defined by me will be there. However, not only them. For instance, all Entity Framework attributes like `EdmScalarPropertyAttribute` are there too. What attributes won't be treated as custom?

Comment: Not sure to understand. Are you asking what is a "custom attribute" vs an "attribute"?

Comment: I think it is the point.

Comment: 2ken2k: yes. Both generally, and in terms of `GetCustomAttributes` method, if there are differences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost every attribute that's derived from `System.Attribute` and added with the `[AttributeName]` syntax will be there. Some of them are even added by the compiler itself, such as `OutAttribute` for the `out` keyword.

The word "custom" distinguishes them from attributes that are built directly into the runtime, such as the visibility of a member/type, a method being `static`, `virtual` or `sealed`, etc.

For example `Type.Attributes` is an enum of type [`TypeAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeattributes.aspx), or `MethodBase.Attributes` corresponds to the [`MethodAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodattributes.aspx) enum. Those don't count as "custom".

---

There are some strange corner cases, regarding `[Serializable]` and memory layout.

Essential C# [writes](http://books.google.de/books?id=qa8UUSxq8Q0C&pg=PT933&lpg=PT933&dq=SerializableAttribute+pseudoattribute&source=bl&ots=xl5b_sV85x&sig=UErQB1PwE3bC0wvlqVTNnUD5gx8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=C_oXUICmDMje4QS994DwAw&ved=0CGEQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=SerializableAttribute%20pseudoattribute&f=false):

> One of the characteristics that make `System.SerializableAttribute` not just a custom attribute, however, is the fact that the CIL has a special header notation for serializable classes.
>
> ...
>
> `SerializableAttribute` translates to a set bit within the metadata tables. This makes `SerializableAttribute` a *pseudoattribute*, an attribute that sets bits or fields in the metadata tables.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Looks like for end-user (programmer) there is a confusion, as Custom Attribute and Attribute are completely different things.

Comment: Typically we call custom attributes just attributes. So it's certainly unfortunate terminology.